# How can I avoid wrapping my block into <div> tags?

Tags: 8, theming

I have created a custom block

```
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "block_text",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Text"),
 *   category = @Translation("Text"),
 * )
 */
```

And here is a `build()` function

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {

  return [
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => $render,
    '#cache' => [
      'max-age' => 0
    ],
  ];

}
```

On the page my block is wrapped into

```
<div id="block_text"> </div> tags
```

Could you please tell me, how can I avoid this wrapping?

Comment: Which theme do you use? Let's hope it's a sub-theme. Then you simply can copy `block.html.twig` from the base theme to your sub-theme and remove that `<div>`. Alternatively you can implement a theme suggestion to pick-up any other custom block template from a custom location, if I remember it right.

Comment: How can I tell my class to use a sub-theme? Currently it uses block.html.twig, but by editing this file I destroy other pages.

Comment: Enable [Twig debugging](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates) to get template suggestion printed into your Markup as HTML comments. Then you will see what other template names you also can use to only override this one specific block. Something like `block--machine-name.html.twig`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should copy `block.html.twig` (perhaps from /core/themes/classy/block/block.html.twig) in your custom module/theme and make it work for your specific block by naming it `block--BLOCKID.html.twig` and remove the outer `<div>` from this twig file.

Alternativelly you can create a [custom template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module)